# sha1sum mismatch!

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wine

Добрый час, дорогие пользователи СО.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему: при установке шрифта "Tahoma" с помощью winetricks получаю ошибку:

> sha1sum mismatch!  Rename
>   /home/devastated/.cache/winetricks/tahoma/tahoma32.exe and try again.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего убедитесь, что у вас winetricks последней версии (`20170614-next` на данный момент). Обновите его, если нужно (`winetricks --self-update`).

У вас в кеше уже содержится битая версия этого шрифта, удалите директорию `/home/devastated/.cache/winetricks/tahoma` и попробуйте установить его снова. Я проверил, у меня устанавливается.

Comment: *sudo winetricks --self-update* — какой кошмар…

Comment: @alexanderbarakin что не так?

Comment: Ну если winetricks установлен от имени пользователя, то без sudo. self-update - это самый простой способ получить последнюю версию. Не через apt же. В чём кошмар? Я не понимаю.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ok, пусть будет без sudo. Я написал sudo на всякий случай, если вдруг скрипт установлен через apt. Хотя, вероятно, что и в этом случае права суперпользователя не нужны, не проверял. В этом комар?

Comment: Хотя нет, кажется я всё правильно написал... Вот пример: https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/783 здесь дают точно такой же совет: You're using an old version of Winetricks, please update sudo winetricks --self-update and try again.

Comment: *если вдруг скрипт установлен через apt* — тем более не стоит советовать в таком случае выполнять какие-то «самообновления»

Comment: *здесь дают точно такой же совет* — пусть этот вредный совет будет на их совести.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin почему же? Ведь apt не содержит последней версии, а без неё проблему возможно и не решить. Какой вариант предложите вы?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin проблема может заключаться именно в том, что winetricks пытается качать шрифт из устаревших источников (хотя там скорее всего мусор в кэше, но не суть).

Comment: программа *apt* вообще не «содержит» никаких версий. так же как и программа *winetricks*. я подозреваю, что файл `tahoma32.exe` на сайте *microsoft* не изменялся уже пару десятков лет, и у автора вопроса некорректно скачался либо сам этот файл, либо файл с контрольной суммой (который, насколько помню, лежит не на сайте *microsoft*, а на одном из множества перенаправляющих серверов, которыми как раз и пользуется программа *winetricks*). в любом случае совет «обновить winetricks», по-моему, абсолютно излишен.

Comment: Репозитории лично моей убунты содержат версию 20170101, а последняя, которую можно получить через self-update 20170614. Я по своему опыту знаю, что winetricks имеют привычку качать софт с различных зеркал, далеко не всегда с официальных источников.

Comment: Обновив winetricks смог установить, теперь другая проблема... С net framework'ом...